# Binding to a DependencyProperty via ViewModel has no effect

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties, code-behind

I've simplified my problem (it means that the principle is similar, but I don't want to cast a int to string ...):

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid>

        <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 CurrentNumber="{Binding Path=TheSpecialNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the Main Window is the UserControl1 appear. The usercontrol has a property Current Number. This I would like to bind the property TheSpecialNumber (the ViewModel).

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;

            _viewModel.TheSpecialNumber = "8";
            _viewModel.UpdateTheSpecialNumberBinding();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string TheSpecialNumber { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void UpdateTheSpecialNumberBinding()
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TheSpecialNumber"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Height="200" Width="300" Background="Aqua">
    <Grid Name="container">
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentNumberIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">0</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">4</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">5</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">6</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">7</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">8</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="20">9</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The UserControl is a ComboBox. This has 10 items. I want to always display the item that has the same number as the property Current Number. Therefore, the binding of Current Number Index.

**UserControl1.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentNumber", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            container.DataContext = this;

            CurrentNumber = "5";
        }

        public string CurrentNumber
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CurrentNumberProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CurrentNumberProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentNumberIndex");
            }
        }

        public int CurrentNumberIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(CurrentNumber);
            }
            set
            {
                CurrentNumber = Convert.ToString(value);
            }
        }

        #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Now my question. Why only the ComboBox items is displayed with the content of 0, if I do in the MainWindow (via ViewModel) the set 8? Even if I make a breakpoint in the setter of Current Number, I stop only once, namely at the 5, but not at the 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might "destroy" the binding between TheSpecialNumber and CurrentNumber by setting CurrentNumber=5 manuelly. Remove this part and try again.

EDIT:
Ok, if this doesnt work, try the following:

1. Add a new PropertyChangedCallback to your PropertyMetaData:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentNumber", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata( new PropertyChangedCallback(CurrentNumberPropertyChanged)));
   ```
2. Set CurrentNumber in this Method like:

   ```
   private static void CurrentNumberPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   {
       UserControl1 uc1 = (UserControl1)dependencyObject;
       uc1.CurrentNumber = (string)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
   }
   ```

Comment: If I remove `CurrentNumber = "5";`, nothing changes

Comment: See my Edit (based on ChrisDD's solution).

Comment: Yes almost, but what I meant that is you need to add OnPropertyCHanged("CurrentIndexNumber") into PropertyChanged callback.

Comment: But through     uc1.CurrentNumber = (string)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue; the setter of CurrentNumber is called, which includes     OnPropertyChanged("CurrentNumberIndex");

Answer (score 1):

CurrentNumber is WPF property which means that if WPF uses that property, it's gonna pass the getter/setter of CurrentNumber.

So essentially when you set TheSpecialNumber, this part wont be executed:

```
 SetValue(CurrentNumberProperty, value);
 OnPropertyChanged("CurrentNumberIndex");
```

Hook yourself into WPF propertys UI property metadata.

Comment: Did I have understood it correctly: should I give 5 as FrameworkPropertyMetadata?

`DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentNumber", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("5"));`

Comment: See Florian answer but add OnPropertyChanged into CurrentNumberPropertyChanged event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentNumberIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In Binding of SelectedIndex the binding system will look for CurrentNumberIndex property in UserControl DataContext which is your ViewModel and it doesnt find this property there so to get it working set RelativeSource to Self. I hope this will  help.